# Substring size advice

Tags: vb.net

If using the following in an if statement I get an error:

```
If trg.Name.Substring(4, 6).ToUpper <> ("ABCDEF") Then
```

I get the error:
"Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"

I assume this is because the string (trg.name) is too small for the 4, 6 substring.
What would be the correct method of working around this problem?

Thanks,
madlan.

VB.net Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If (trg.Name.IndexOf("ABCDEF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <> 4) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

*Instr* returns the index of where the searched string is first found. So If you could do this:

```
If InStr(trg.Name, "ABCDEF", CompareMethod.Text) - 1 <> 4 Then
```

With InStr you dont have to check lenght of trg.Name.

Comment: LukeH:s example is better (using the string-objects .IndexOf), but I leave my answer as it is for variation and information.

Answer (score 0):

You should likely be checking that the length of `trg.Name` is at least (4+6) characters long.

Comment: trg.name can be any length. I'm looking for any that fit 123_ABCDEF***
The only constant is 4, 6 (ABCDEF) which I need to look for.